# WWW::Mechanize - Grab <form> action for variable to pass to $url2

Tags: perl

I've using WWW-Mechanize to login to a page for years, submit form data, then grab the data/display it etc. The problem is now the source site where I am grabbing from has started using another variable after the login (the POST data) which is a dynamic URL at random times (it's the user ID of the person I've logged in with, seems to be changing.) I can't seem to find a way to grab the action link to store it as a variable: $url2

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" action="../Emsresponse/?id=106"  onsubmit="return validate()">
```

When I run my code, I store the original $url as well as $url2, which is a slightly different /real/ URL with variables at the, but it's becoming dynamic so I need to store the action part and in $url2 so I don't have to keep changing the static URLs variables.

For example, this was working:

```
my $url = "www.whatever.com/form";
my $url2 = "www.whatever.com/Ems/id?102";
```

I simply need to store the data within action (ie: ../Emsresponse/?id=106) as a variable, but I cannot find a reliable way to do this with Mechanize.

So I need $url2 to contain the ?id=whatever-it-is-now so I don't have to keep modifying the code every 2 weeks.

```
$url  = "www.page.com";
$url2 = "www.page.com/userName/id?=101";
my $r = $mech->get($url2);

#  if we are not logged in $r hold has a key previous holding the http response from the 302 redirect call to the login page
if (1) {

    # if we were redirected to the login location we are not logged in
    if (1) {
        $mech->get($url);
        if ( $mech->success() ) {
            $mech->form_name("loginForm");
            $mech->set_fields( LoginUserName => ... );
            $mech->click();
            if ( $mech->success() ) {
                $authme = 0;
            }

            # check for success --> this is important to not break the script on any errors
            if (   $authme == 0
                && $mech->success() )
            {
                $mech->cookie_jar->save($cookie_file);

                $mech->form_name("searchForm");
                $mech->set_fields( DateStart => $date_yesterday );
                $mech->click();
                if ( $mech->success() ) { }
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question and show the actual code that you are using with WWW::Mechanize and say what it is you are trying to achieve. Where does `$url` come from in your program? What is `$url2` and why do you need it? What do you want to do with those two URLs?

Comment: What does your code do? Do you parse out the _action_ from that HTML and then submit another request? Why don't you just use Mechanize to fill in the form and submit it? It will use the correct action, unless it's done via JS (in which case parsing it won't help either).

Comment: Yes, I parse the HTML page via scraping. It's 2 different FORM requests, one to login, one for data/data/time.

Comment: I've added the code section that is in production. I had to wrap them with if(1) because the server got rid of 3xx redirection and uses dynamic URLs

Comment: That looks like it would work. Add debugging to see what action for the `loginForm` Mechanize sees. Also, there's no scraping in that code.

Answer (score -1):

Seems there was a serverside issue causing this problem..